# Error using summarize function in R using a custom statistic

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, summarize

I'm trying to calculate some statistic called FAR for each group in my data. I wrote a function for calculating the statistic, and it looks like this:

```
FAR <- function(data){
  FAs = sum(data$response %in% c(0,1) & data$correct_response=="No")
  NF = sum(data$correct_response=="No")
  return(FAs/NF)
}
```

My data frame is called subjects_no_imagery, and it has a column called random_participant_ID that I'd like to group by. I then want to calculate FAR for each group, like so:

```
subjects_no_imagery %>% group_by(random_participant_ID) %>% dplyr::summarize(far = FAR())
```

I keep getting the following error:

> subjects_no_imagery %>% group_by(random_participant_ID) %>% dplyr::summarize(far = FAR())
> Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `far`.
> x argument "data" is missing, with no default
> ℹ Input `far` is `FAR()`.
> ℹ The error occured in group 1: random_participant_ID = "2X2DPZG20H".
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

If I pass the data frame as an argument:

```
subjects_no_imagery %>% group_by(random_participant_ID) %>% dplyr::summarize(FAR = FAR(subjects_no_imagery))
```

then it runs without error, but I get this output, where instead of having a different RAF for each participant, all of the FARs are the same (and equal the the average across all the participants):

```
random_participant_ID   FAR
   <chr>                 <dbl>
 1 2X2DPZG20H            0.196
 2 4GF789C0F0            0.196
 3 93JKYDEZVY            0.196
 4 9J9QM4C7LV            0.196
```

The command

```
subjects_no_imagery %>% group_by(random_participant_ID) %>% dplyr::summarize(FAR = FAR(subjects_no_imagery %>% group_by(random_participant_ID)))
```

also produces the same result.

Any ideas how I can get the FAR statistic for each group?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that FAR function required a dataset, and summarize only works with functions that just use columns.

Instead, I should have done the following:

```
subjects_no_imagery_stats <- subjects_no_imagery %>% group_by(random_participant_ID) %>% 
  summarize(FAs = sum(response %in% c(0,1) & correct_response=="No"), NF = sum(correct_response=="No"), FA_rate = FAs/NF)
```